# Button from web builder avaliable on website in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to make available a button from website builder module on website page (create a new page) in odoo 12. Is it possible? Where should i declare this action/button except template. Now the button only appears on template, but nothing happens.

```
<template id="add_fields_product" inherit_id="website_sale.product">
  <xpath expr="//div[@id='product_details']" position="before">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/domain_sale/static/src/css/my.css"/>
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
       <div groups="base.group_system" name="module_website_sale" t-att-data-module-id="env.ref('base.module_website_sale').id" t-att-data-module-shortdesc="env.ref('base.module_website_sale').shortdesc">
       <a href="#" data-action="new_page">
          <p>New page</p>
       </a>
     </div>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: You have to display a button in the specific product page. Am I Right?

Comment: Yes, button must create a new page. Now it is avaliable  in website constructor menu